# How export a module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

emailConfirmation.js:

```
var configAuth = require('../../authentication/sendgrid');
var sendgrid = require('sendgrid')(configAuth.sg.username, configAuth.sg.password);

var from_address = "mycompany@pubcrawlsp.com";
var text_body = "sometextbody";
var html_body = "somehtml";
```

Them i need export in my routes, to use in a post route, like this:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {

     sendgrid.send({
        to:         req.body.email,
        from:       the from_adrres variable from the other file,
        subject:    "Some subjec",
        text:       the text_body variable from the other file
        html:       the html_body variable from the other file
    }, function(err, json) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log(json);
});


});
```

How can i export the emailConfirmation.js and use like that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating a file just for your code.

At the end of the file, you would "expose" parts of the code to a consumer. For example:

In your case you could wrap your code like so:

```
module.exports.set = function(app) {
  app.post('/', function(req, res) { 
      /* the post code goes here */ 
  });
};
```

You could consume it with app.js like so on app.js:

```
require('./sendgrid').set(app);
```

This would effectively set your route(s) for sendgrid.

Comment: Hei @Jason, thanks for your answer.. i update the question for better understand.. can u check?

Comment: There is a special place in my heart for anonymous down-voters.